# Unpivot multiple columns into two distinct ones without VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I've got a dataset that has thousands of rows and multiple columns for questions and answers that expand horizontally. I would like to unpivot all the "Questions" columns into one and do the same for the corresponding "Answers" columns.

My dataset looks like this:

`Header1 Header2 Q1 A1  Q2  A2
 560-19  Bill   A   A'  B   B'
 560-33  Jay    A   A'  B   B'
 560-34  Nick   A   A'  B   B'
 490-31  Julia  A   A'  B   B'
 490-32  Anna   A   A'  B   B'
 490-33  Reed   A   A'  B   B'
 900-87  Mick   A   A'  B   B'`

and I want to transform it into this:

`Header1 Header2 Q  A
560-19   Bill    A  A'
560-19   Bill    B  B'
560-33   Jay     A  A'
560-33   Jay     B  B'
560-34   Nick    A  A'
560-34   Nick    B  B'
490-31   Julia   A  A'
490-31   Julia   B  B'
490-32   Anna    A  A'
490-32   Anna    B  B'
490-33   Reed    A  A'
490-33   Reed    B  B'
900-87   Mick    A  A'
900-87   Mick    B  B'`

I am using Excel 365.

Comment: Use Power Query

Comment: Is there a certain way to do it in Power Query because what I've tried so far with it has not produced the desired result.

Comment: *"What I've tried so far with [Power Query] has not produced the desired result."* - It might be worth it to [edit] your question and expand on the exact steps you tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in Power Query (most but not all steps can be done in the UI), with your setup (and could be with multiple q/a pairs of columns) try:

- Select the two Header columns and then `Unpivot other columns`
- Add index column
- Remove `Attribute` column
- Transform the Index column into an Integer-Divided column (div by 2) to create a series of `{0,0,1,1,2,2,...}`
- Group rows by the transformed Index column into a Record ***this cannot be done from the UI***
- Remove the Index column
- Expand the values in the grouped column and rename the new columns `A` and `Q`

#### Original Data

[image]

#### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Header1", "Header2"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Index",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Integer-Divided Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns", {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 2), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Integer-Divided Column", {"Index", "Header1","Header2"},{{"Values", each Record.FromList([Value], {"Header1","Header2"}), type record}}),
    RemIndex = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Index"}),
    ExpandValues = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(RemIndex,"Values",{"Header1","Header2"},{"Q","A"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(ExpandValues,{{"Header1", type text}, {"Header2", type text}, {"Q", type text}, {"A", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

#### Results

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it worked perfectly at my personal system. I haven't implemented it at work yet cause we use a different language package. Grouping rows is not feasible in Power Query's UI, right? So I'll have to add a step and then adjust the formula you provided into Power Query's formula bar.

Comment: @JayVee You can group rows from the UI.  But the result is a Table and we need a List

Comment: @ Ron, you are right, it is obvious from the resulted table after the "grouping of rows" step. I will give it a try, making the appropriate language adjustments to the code and hope it works as well.

Comment: @JayVee I should have written `Record`, not `List`